# uploadify Characters (čžćšđ) issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using http://www.uploadify.com/ but when I upload images with character (čžćšđ) like "čžćšđ.jpg" čćžšđ is corrupted and uploaded image looks like ÄŤÄ‡ĹľĹˇÄ‘.jpg.

How can I prevent this? What to do that čžšđ will work after upload?

Comment: Have you synchronised the page encoding on client and server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on uploadifys encoding and there is only one thing you can do about it:

Change the characters in your file.

I highly doubt that it will be fixed soon, even if you tell them about the problem. Either use someone else or change the name of your files.